# CSS Center recaptcha object

Tags: css

Any idea how I can center [this](http://olm-consulting.com/) recaptcha object at the bottom of the page? I have tried to `text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;` to all parent objects and it is still stuck on the left.

Comment: add to `.wpcf7-form-control-wrap { display: inline-block; }`

Comment: You need to set the `wpcf7-form-control-wrap` with `text-align:center` and the captcha with `margin:auto`

Comment: @Koby Douek They already have it set above on the parent.

Comment: @jtrein It should be directly on `.wpcf7-form-control-wrap`

Comment: No. Styles cascade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the div around the captcha the following styles:

```
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap {
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't styling what's inside iframe. do this, or give the parent of that div text-align center
[image]

Comment: I don;t think this div is available in the markup to write the code.

Comment: Can just select its parent. I did say "give the parent of that div text-align center". in this case he can do .wpcf7-form-control-wrap {text-align: center;} or .wpcf7-form-control {text-align: center} or .wpcf7-form-control > div {margin: 0 auto;}

Answer (score 1):

**Here are few solutions you can try:**
**Solution 1:**

```
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap{ display:inline-block; text-align:center;}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
.wpcf7-form-control.g-recaptcha{ max-width:304px; margin:0px auto;}
```

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
#recaptcha-box {
    width: 304px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="recaptcha-box">
<div id="getdata" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxx"></div>
</div>
```